# Convert SQL statement in SAS to POSTGRESQL

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis

How do I get this SQL code that worked in SAS to work in POSTGRESQL.  Below is the code that worked in SAS but not in POSTGRESQL.

```
newname='Other';

if fullstate='Alaska' then equal_area_id='RAINIER';

if fullstate='Hawaii' then equal_area_id='SHASTA';

if fullstate='California' then equal_area_id='SHASTA'; 

if fullstate='California' and county in    (45 21 7 63 91 57 33 11 10143 47 99 77 67 109 9 5 17 61 115 113 55 97 95 3)   then equal_area_id='MENDOCINO';
```

This below script kind of works in POSTGRESQL but it only labels the new field as "TEMECULA" and not "SHIPROCK"

```
UPDATE new_counties2

SET newname = CASE     
WHEN fullstate = 'Arizona' THEN 'TEMECULA' 

WHEN fullstate = 'Arizona' AND county IN ('1', '17', '5', '15', '7') THEN 'SHIPROCK' END
WHERE newname IN ('Other')
```

This is going to be for the whole country so I need to get the formatting straight somehow.

Comment: That isn't SAS SQL - it does look like a data step. Typically you convert to SQL via a Case statements.

Answer (score 3):

The order of conditions in a `case` expression is important.

Let's say there are 3 conditions,

```
case when condition1 then 1
     when condition2 then 2
     when condition3 then 3
end
```

If condition1 is satisfied for a row, condition2 and condition3 will not be evaluated. Similarly if condition1 fails and condition2 is satisfied, condition3 will not be checked.

To get the desired result, use

```
CASE
WHEN fullstate = 'Arizona' AND county IN ('1', '17', '5', '15', '7') THEN 'SHIPROCK'
WHEN fullstate = 'Arizona' THEN 'TEMECULA'
END
```

Comment: If the order of conditions is out of sync in my list is there a better way to populate the "newname" field or is the CASE expression the only way to go about this

Comment: do you mean order of counties in `county IN ('1', '17', '5', '15', '7')`? If so, that doesn't matter.

Comment: You should build a lookup table instead and then use a join. Keeping logic like this in the code is hard to maintain over time and prone to errors. You'll have similar errors with the California case above as well.

Comment: No not the order of counties.  RIght now when I run that snippet of code about Arizona the "newname" column only populates with "TEMECULA" and not "SHIPROCK" perhaps it has something to do with the WHERE statement? @Reeza I am very new to SQL and do not know how to create a lookup table, I would like to read up on it, any suggestions?

Comment: It has to do with the order. When executing if the state is Arizona the first WHEN statement is true so the next statement is never checked.

Answer (score 1):

We can create some example data:

```
create table test (fullname varchar(20), county integer);
\copy test from stdin with delimiter ',';
Alaska,1
Arizona,2
California,5
California,6
\.
```

For the first of two alternative approaches, we could consider nested case statements:

```
select county, fullname,
   case fullname
     when 'Alaska' then 'RAINIER'
     when 'Arizona' then 'SHASTA'
     when 'California' then case
          when county in (45, 21, 7, 63, 91, 57, 33, 11, 10143, 47, 99, 77, 67, 109, 9, 5, 17, 61, 115, 113, 55, 97, 95, 3) then 'MENDOCINO'
          else 'SHASTA' end
     else ''
     end as equal_area_id
from test 
order by county;
```

This logic may be easier to follow for some readers. Second, and more closely to the datastep code, we could use plpgsql:

```
create or replace function equal_area_id(fullname varchar(20), county integer) returns varchar(10)
as $$
begin
    if fullname='Alaska' then return 'ALASKA';
    elsif fullname='Arizona' then return 'SHASTA';
    elsif fullname='California' and county in (45, 21, 7, 63, 91, 57, 33, 11, 10143, 47, 99, 77, 67, 109, 9, 5, 17, 61, 115, 113, 55, 97, 95, 3) then return 'MENDOCINO'; 
    elsif fullname='California' then return 'SHASTA';
    end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select county, fullname, equal_area_id(fullname,county)
from test
order by county;
```

This is not as concise as the SAS datastep, but is more modularised. Both approaches give the same output:

```
 county |  fullname  | equal_area_id 
--------+------------+---------------
      1 | Alaska     | ALASKA
      2 | Arizona    | SHASTA
      5 | California | MENDOCINO
      6 | California | SHASTA
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently hardcoding the rules into your code. I recommend building a table to hold those values and then use a join instead.

Somehow in your system create a table that maps the State and Counties to a equal_area_id.

```
State County Equal_area_id
AZ  1 Temecula
AZ  2 Temecula
AZ  3 Shiprock
NV  1 Vegas
NV  2 Vegas
CA  1 Shasta
CA 45 Mendocino
CA 21 Mendocino
```

Then use a join in postgresql rather than case statements. This way if you need to make updates, you update your table and your code stays the same.